# Load packages based on commands in document

Tags: packages, compiling

I've got a custom class which I've taken a few of the 'heavy' components out of and put into their own packages (i.e. loading and configuring minted, chemfig). At the moment if I start, doing maths, writing chemisty, including code blocks etc. I need to remember to add a class option or load one of my sub-packages.

Something I'd really like to do is after the stage at which all `\import`/`\input` commands are run, to search for relevant commands in the document, and then load the relevant sub-packages as needed, such that I get the full set of features without having to think about what sub-packages I need, or suffering from the performance loss of having them all enabled.

#### TLDR;

I want to dynamically determine whether a package is needed based on search strings to be run on the document (e.g. `\begin{minted}`) and then load them as required.

Does anyone know if this would be possible?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this within TeX in a meaningful way. You could collect the whole document (assuming you don't run into memory problems) and perform the checks, but once the document body has been collected all catcodes are frozen, so a lot of stuff will not work any more. I believe the only meaningful way to do this is through a shell script.

Comment: That's a bit annoying. I'll still hold out some hope as I recently read from a manual "chemmacros loads the packages expl3[L3Pa] and xparse[L3Pb]. Depending on your usage other packages will be loaded."

Comment: The "depending on your usage" in the `chemmacros` doc refers to issuing `\chemsetup{module=...}` somewhere in the preamble, not in the middle of the document.

Comment: Oh well. As a partial solution, would it be possible to do it just based on the un-procesed contents of the current tex file?

Comment: No, that's quite the point: TeX reads the document line by line and has no way to look at the unprocessed contents of the file without at least pre-processing them (i.e. assigning character and category codes).

Comment: you could obviously do this in an external script, but tex never reads the document in to memory. if you start using chemistry in chapter 3, tex won't see that until after it has already  fully processed the entire document up to that point. Tex typically only holds enough to make a little over a page in memory.

Comment: Thanks, David. Do you know if it would it be possible to: on initial compile dump the commands called into an external file, then immediately halt compilation. Then on running again use `\write18` to call a script which determines which packages to use. Does that sound feasable/reasonable?

Comment: Why not just run a script in the first place?

Comment: Not in any reliable way. If your first undefined command is minted, and you haven't loaded the package then you need to stop then so can't discover any other packages not loaded, also for this to work you'd have to always run with shell-escape enabled which is a massive security risk.

Answer (score 2):

TeX never holds the document in memory it just processes the input line by line, so it has no possibility of scanning ahead to see use of a command from package.

You could use an external search with a tool such as grep or perl to look at a document and guess needed packages although this is unlikley to be reliable.  Something like minted is likely to be visible by a simple search as verbatim-like arguments are necessarily at the top level so `\begin{minted}`  is likely to be explicit in a document, but fi you find `\Question` you are not going to easily know to load `stix2` package (or `stix` package, or switch from pdflatex to lualatex or xelatex and use `unicode-math`) without a massve and hard to maintain lookup table detailing thousands of commands and possible packages that define them.